# Is it possible to predefine max value of Y axis in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, swing, charts, jfreechart

This is what I've tried:

```
   XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
   ValueAxis yAxis = plot.getRangeAxis();
   yAxis.setRange(0.0, 4000.0);   
   XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
   ValueAxis yAxis = plot.getRangeAxis();
   yAxis.setRange(0.0, 4000.0);
```

But I got this exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot cannot be cast to org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Presumably chart.getPlot() returns a CategoryPlot.  As the error message says, you can't cast a CategoryPlot to a XYPlot.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is pretty self explanatory: you are trying to cast the result of  `chart.getPlot()` call as a `XYPlot` class instance but it's actually a `CategoryPlot` instead.

You may find in the [JFreeChart docs](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html) the appropriate way to set the chart `Plot` as needed, i.e.: `XYPlot`, and then set the range you want.

Hint: look at the `JFreeChart` class [constructor](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html#JFreeChart-org.jfree.chart.plot.Plot-).

You may also want to take a look to [JFreeChart#getXYPlot()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html#getXYPlot--):

> Returns the plot cast as an `XYPlot`.
>
> NOTE: if the plot is not an instance of `XYPlot`, then a
>   `ClassCastException` is thrown.

Comment: im new to jfreechart. can u give me some sample code for it?

Comment: No, I can't. There are a lot of examples here in Stack Overflow. Just Google for them! :)

Comment: dude.. seriously? :p ok il give a shot

Comment: @DoorDUthpala: Also check the [source code](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html) of your chosen [`ChartFactory`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html) see what plot it's using.